# @media query not working for all rules

Tags: html, css, media

I'm really stuck on this one because my @media query works for the first rule, but not anything after it.

For example I have the "subButton" disappear when the screen goes below the set width, but I also need to change the `h2` heading size down to `2.5em` (currently `4.5em` on a desktop). However only the `subButton` is altered by the media query when viewed on my iPhone.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

*** Edit *** I have included the code that I am targeting with the media query. I have tried all of the different classes, id's but still no luck. Any further insight is much appreciated

```
/** Mobile **/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
    #subButton
    {
        display:none;
    } 
    .primaryContainer h2 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="contentContainer" id="primaryBackground">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 primaryContainer">
                            <h2>Get Rocket Ship Growth!</h2><br>
                            <p>Weekly Step by Step Growth Hacking<br>Guides & Actionable Insight</p>
                            <button><a href="#section2">Learn More &or;</a></button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Where you are implementing this CSS ? Can you please paste the code..

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to specificity. I've tested it and it works fine. You are missing the final closing brace in that block though. Inspect  `.primaryContainer h2` and see what styles are active. There's probably an additional class or id being called and applied to it from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I feel like I am on the right path but am still having trouble. I did have the final brace in the code, just copied it over wrong.

I have added in the code that I am actually trying to change with the media query. I have tried all the different classes and id's but can't seem to get it to work. 

Im guessing my codes a bit of a mess, as im a fairly new to this

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1) What is `#subButton`? I assume it is the `<button>`.

2) Take out the `only`. I don't see why you would have it. Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't think it's the correct syntax.

3) Why do you need both `max-width` and `max-device-width`? Isn't that redundant? If a device is 500px, do you expect the window size to be 600px? Therefore, you only need to do `max-width`, since it doesn't exceed the `max-device-width`.

I have it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/wfkr3w50/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
.primaryContainer h2 {font-size: 2.5em !important;}
```

check whether you're enabled viewport

```
"meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1""
```